# ZeroMQ server/client with AWS EC2

Tags: c++, windows, amazon-ec2, zeromq

Hello I wrote a very simple ZMQ server and client application. It works fine on my local machine and it also works fine if I run both apps from within AWS (same security group). I have tried opening the correct port in the AWS security group (both inbound and outbound). I even opened them to All traffic on any port/address. But I don't receive the published messages on my client.

My client code looks like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "zmq.hpp"

static std::string s_recv (zmq::socket_t &socket) 
{
    zmq::message_t message;
    socket.recv(&message);
    return std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size()-1);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
     std::string adrStr = argv[1];
     zmq::context_t context (1);
     zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);

     std::cout << "Connecting to server..." << std::endl;
     subscriber.connect(adrStr.c_str());
     const char *filter ="Sending ";

     subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, filter ,strlen(filter));

     int update_nbr=0;
     for (update_nbr=0; update_nbr<100; update_nbr++)
     {
          zmq::message_t update;
          std::string msg_s=s_recv(subscriber);
          std::cout<<"Received something..."<<msg_s<<std::endl;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

My server side code looks like this

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "zmq.hpp"

int main () 
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);

    std::cout << "Binding to port ..." << std::endl;

    publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");

    int cnt =0;
    while(1)
    {
         char buffer[30];
         int msgn=0;
         msn = sprint_s(buffer, "Sending number %d", cnt);
         std::cout<<buffer<<std::endl;
         zmq::message_t message(30);
         memcpy((void*) message.data(), buffer,30);

         publisher.send(message);

         Sleep(1);
         cnt++;
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

In the client app command line I tried passing in the public DNS correctly formatted as 
"TCP://public-dns:5556"
I also tried with the public TCP/IP

Anyone knows what I might be missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so thanks to a friend who helped me figuring out what was going on here is the answer :

basically the application was running on a Windows Server 2012 instance and the windows firewall was preventing any traffic towards my application. Adding the application to the allowed applications list for the windows firewall did the trick.

so here is a recap on what to do to make it work

my server app is now bind to tcp://*:5556    and my client connects to   tcp://public-ip:5556

via the EC2 console management , add the security group rule

Custom TCP  Aywhere on port 5556

on the server make sure you add the server executable to the allowed applications list.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an elastic IP address and tying that to a route 53 dns name and using that. It should resolve to the private IP address for machines on the AWS network. Using the private IP or private dns name alone will never be promised to stay the same.

Comment: I have an Elastic IP associated to my EC2 instance. As mentioned above I have opened all traffic on my instance as well. If I try to bind my server app to tcp://ec2-54-187-31-169.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5556 then my server app crashes when attempting to bind.

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong but this is what I am supposed to do to make it work in theory : 
    My server app binds to its private IP with i.e. port 5556
    I open the public TCP port  5556  for all inbound addresses
    I connect my client to the public IP address on port 5556

I am not sure where the Route 53 service fits in this , I don't have a web-domain registered that I would want to use. As far as I understand assigning an elastic IP to my instance should provide it with a static IP so my clients can always connect to that IP.

Comment: You may be able to set up a private virtual network within AWS too but I haven't worked with those before. You are setting up 53 name because it will resolve to the private IP that you want even though it points to the public elastic IP. Also, do you have these two ec2 instances under the same aws security group with the port allowed inbound traffic from the security group? If not that might be a way to start before setting up 53. Then use the private dns address just to test (not good for production because it can/will change)

Comment: Just to be clear , I am trying to connect to my server from my home computer not from another instance.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not reading the question more clearly. It would help if you showed the exact rules you implemented.

Comment: Here are the inbound rules i have tried so far... 
Custom TCP rule , Port 5000 - 6000, Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 | 
All TCP, Port 0 - 65535, Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 | 
All Traffic, Port 0 - 65535, Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0 | 
Custom TCP, Port 5556, Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0  | 

i also tried using the specific addresses of both my public IP and Private IP...

the outbound by default is ...

All Traffic, Port 0 - 65535, Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0